# Understanding django ModelForm submission

Tags: python, django, comments, submit, modelform

I'm trying to create comment system in a blog. This is the view section.

```
def post_content(request,post_slug):
   post= Post.objects.get(slug=post_slug)
   new_comment=None

   #get all comments that are currently active to show in the post
   comments= post.comments.filter(active=True)

   if request.method=='POST':
    comment_form= CommentForm(request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        # saving a ModelForm creates an object of the corresponding model. 
        new_comment= comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post=post
        new_comment.save()

   else:
    comment_form=CommentForm()
return render(request,'blog/post_content.html',{'post':post,'comments':comments,'comment_form':comment_form})
```

There's no comment yet. Now, what I don't understand is when I post a comment and then page reloads, I immediately see the comment (which I shouldn't be).

By my understanding, this should be the flow- When the page reloads(after submitting comment), it goes to views and retrieves active comments first (*which should be empty because none has been saved yet, has it?*) It is saved only when the if condition is satisfied and form is valid , which are all below. And I haven't retrieved comments after saving. But still, the '**comments**' variable contains the  recent comment I made. 
How is this happening ? What sorcery is this ? Please somebody make it clear for me !!

Comment: In case of a succesfull submission, you should `return redirect(..)`, to some page, for example a list of comments, or the same form (that will then be empty)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That'll solve the resubmission problem I had been having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Although you create the queryset before saving the comment, the query isn't actually made until you iterate, which happens in the template itself after the new comment has been saved.

Note that, as Willem points out in the comment, you really should redirect to another page after a successful save. This is to prevent duplicate submission if the user refreshes the page. You can redirect back to the same page if you like, but the important thing is that you return a redirect rather than falling through to the render.

```
new_comment.save()
return redirect('post-comment', post_slug=post_slug)
```